# Hardware virtualization

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

Is there a way to enable hardware virtualization for VMWare on Windows 7 if the CPU doesn't support this?

Answer (score 8):

No.  The name "hardware virtualization" specifically indicates that the feature is based in hardware.  If the CPU does not have the instruction set, you cannot enable it otherwise.

Intel's [testing the market](http://www.thaindian.com/newsportal/entertainment/intel-offers-cpu-upgrade-card_100436107.html) with "software enabled" upgrades but I believe it to be cores and cache, not instruction set.